# Angular 2 Click Event: Change image, then change route

Tags: angular, typescript, click, angular2-routing

I am trying to change a button image src AND route the user to another page on click. Here is what I have tried.

**home.component.html**

```
<button class="hexagon"
        (click)="gotoFinishing()">
    <img [src]="imgsrc">
</button>
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {

    constructor( private router: Router) { }

    imgsrc="test.png";

    gotoFinishing(){
        this.imgsrc="test2.png";
        let link = ['/finishing'];
        this.router.navigate(link);
    }
}
```

It does not change the image src, but it does route the user to the correct page. Is there a way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: How would you know if the image changes, since you are instantly routing away from the component when the image changes? What's even the point to change the image in your home component if you are routing away from that component? :)

Comment: @AJT_82 It won't let me post the images or else I would show you the goal. We have two images (1) Hexagon with shadow and (2) Hexagon without shadow. We are trying to _create_ a depressed button click when clicked, then route to the page. Does that make sense? If there is a better way that I am willing to try, but because the button is a hexagon it is hard.

Comment: Well it won't work as is, since `goToFinishing` changes the image AND routes away from the component, the new image doesn't have time to render before you are routing away :)

Comment: @AJT_82 Yes I understand that. I am trying to find a way for it to work. `goToFinishing()` can always be changed. I am open to changing it since it **needs** to work.

Comment: You could set a timeout before routing away, that is one option :)

Comment: Thank you! I completely forgot about that option. `gotoFinishing(){
        this.imgsrc="test2.png";
        setTimeout(() => {
            let link = ['/finishing'];
            this.router.navigate(link);
        }, 100);
    }`

Comment: No problem! Yeah, sometimes the most obvious solution gets overseen. Know the feeling, I think everyone can relate :P Happy coding! :)

Comment: Yup! Completely agree. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's "not changing" because as soon as you navigate to another path on the router, the old view is destroyed and thus all state is lost.

You need to decouple the state of your application in order to preserve changes to particular views. To do that, you'll need to create a provider for keeping track of the app state, inject it into the views/components you'll need to use state on, and in the template reference the corresponding state variable within the provider.

Example:

**app.provider.ts**

```
@Injectable()
export class AppProvider {
    public state = {
        Home: {
            imgsrc: 'test.png
        }
    };
}
```

**home.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AppProvider } from './app.provider.ts';

@Component({
    templateUrl: 'home.component.html'
})
export class HomeComponent {
    constructor(
            private router: Router,
            public appProvider: AppProvider
    ) { }

    gotoFinishing(){
        this.appProvider.state.Home.imgsrc="test2.png";

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.router.navigate(['/finishing']);
        }, 1000);
    }
}
```

**home.component.html**

```
<button class="hexagon" (click)="gotoFinishing()">
    <img [src]="appProvider.state.HomeComponent.imgsrc">
</button>
```

Be sure to import and add the AppProvider class into the declarations of your @NgModule so the dependency injection can work.

Hope it helps.

---

**UPDATED ANSWER:**
Added a delay to the routing change so the image change can be seen first.

Comment: Thanks for the help. However it is still routing to the page _before_ you see the change in image.

Comment: Please see my updated answer, in which a 1-second delay was added to the routing change, so the user can see the image change first.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up trying `setTimeout` yesterday and it worked.

Comment: Good to hear that. You may want to mark this question as answered, so it can help other people looking for a similar solution.

Comment: I did, but I do not have enough reputation points so it won't show it. Sorry.

Comment: No worries. Glad to help.